# Зависимость ForeignKey в django, как работает в обратную сторону

Tags: python, mysql, django

Пишу сайт на django. В базе данных mysql есть 2 таблицы (slavneft, electronicsignature зависима от славнефть foreignKey (один ко многим))
Сайт имеет два url (******/users/id - для выводи детальной информации о пользователе из базы slavneft. И ******/es/id - для вывода детальной информации об электронной подписи из базы electronicsignature)
При выводе детальной информации из ЭП я могу получить доступ о ее владельце (базе данных slavneft)
Как мне вывести данные в обратную сторону из владельца найти все его эл подписи?

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ electronicsignature.name_es }}</h1>

  <p><strong>Имя ЭП:</strong> {{ electronicsignature.name_es }}</p>
  <p><strong>Действителен с:</strong> {{ electronicsignature.validity }}</p>
  <p><strong>Действителен до:</strong> {{ electronicsignature.validity_untill }}</p>
  <p><strong>Статус:</strong> {{ electronicsignature.status }}</p>
  <p><strong>Владелец:</strong> {{ electronicsignature.owner }}</p>
  <p><strong>Должность владельца:</strong> {{ electronicsignature.owner.user_position }}</p>

  <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ slavneft.user_name }}</h1>

  <p><strong>Фио сотрудника:</strong> {{ slavneft.user_name }}</p>
  <p><strong>Учетная запись AD:</strong> {{ slavneft.account_ad }}</p>
  <p><strong>Должность:</strong> {{ slavneft.user_position }}</p>
  <p><strong>Отдел:</strong> {{ slavneft.user_department }}</p>
  <p><strong>Тест:</strong> {{ как получить тут все подписи принадлежащие владельцу }}</p>

  <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось куда проще, воспользуемся функцией _set.all для того чтобы получить из базы все модели относящиеся к этому пользователю (slavneft). А затем с помощью цикла выводим все полученные модели.

```html
  <h4>Выданные Электронные подписи</h4>
{% for es in slavneft.electronicsignature_set.all %}
  <dt><a href="{% url 'es-detail' es.pk %}">{{es}}</a> : ({{es.validity}})</dt>
{% endfor %}
```